# How to add extra data from unrelated table in Django Rest?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have this serializer:

```
class RatingSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(source='usersceneobj.user.username')
    image = serializers.SerializerMethodField(source='get_image')
    crystals = serializers.FloatField(source='propertyValue')
    energy = serializers.SerializerMethodField(source='get_energy')

    def get_image(self, obj):
        return obj.usersceneobj.user.extendeduser.get_big_img()

    def get_energy(self, obj):
        return obj.get_energy(obj)

    class Meta:
        model = UserSceneObjectParameter
        fields = '__all__'
```

I wand to add extra column - reward for for the first 5 rows, which is fetching from another table with 2 columns: position(1 - 5) and reward for this position.

How can i do this?

Or may be i need to make 2 queries: to fetch Rating data and then, fetch reward data for the first 5 rows?

My primary model:

```
class UserSceneObjectParameter(models.Model):
    usersceneobj = models.ForeignKey(UserSceneObject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    property = models.ForeignKey(ObjectPropertie)
    propertyValue = models.FloatField(default=0)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def get_energy(self, crystal_param):
        return UserSceneObjectParameter.objects.get(usersceneobj=crystal_param.usersceneobj,
                                                property__propertyTitle='energy').propertyValue
```

And unrelated model, from which i want to fetch extra data for the first 5 rows:

```
class RatingReward(models.Model):
    position = models.IntegerField()
    reward = models.FloatField()

    def __unicode__(self):
       return str(self.position)
```

In django admin this extra reward data looks like: [image]

Comment: Can you add your models?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner I've added models.